# Question about possible relations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, relations

Hello I have a question about possible equivalence relations.

I know that a relation can be Reflexive, Symmetric , Transitive.

But my question is, is there any strict limitations one has on the other.

For example if we had a relation then there are eight possible combinations of the above, for example we could have R S T and not R , S, T, or Not R, Not S, T,
for example.

To me they all seem possible except for a relation that is not reflexive but symmetric and transitive.

Any insight?

Comment: All eight are possible.  The empty relation for example satisfies being not reflexive while being both symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a relation on a set where nothing relates to anything? This is symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive.

Comment: Hm interesting, but how would I write such as a subset of the Cartesian product?

Comment: Like this: $\emptyset$.

Comment: @PersonaA There are more examples beyond the empty relation as well.  So long as there is at least one element $x$ which is not related to anything (especially itself), even if the rest of the relation satisfies symmetry and transitivity, since $x$ is not related to itself, it will not be reflexive.  For example $R\subseteq \{1,2,3\}\times \{1,2,3\}$ with $R=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$